# A word for a person that acts as though they're familiar with/close to someone

Tags: word-request

Is there an adjective to describe someone as if he/she **acts** like they're really close to someone?

I'll try my best to give a context. In this case, a narrative. For a convenient reason, I'll use pronoun *he*.

> Suppose there's a stranger you've seen for the first time. Suddenly,
> he calls you by your name even though you've never met him before. Then, he
> starts a conversation with you. He tells about himself and introduces
> his family and asking you a few questions. It annoys you since you don't know who he is because you've just met him. You also feel a bit uncomfortable because he knows your name and he's not supposed to know. As if you're not ready to build a relation with him. In fact, he realizes that he has just met you for the first time as well.

Perhaps, it's roughly similar to **to be friendly**. But in this case, saying being friendly has a positive connotation and the word, that I'm looking for, has a rather negative connotation. What is it?

Comment: I don't think I've ever experienced what you're describing, so maybe it doesn't culturally translate? (I'm from the northeast US.) As far as language goes though, I'd maybe just use the phrase "overly friendly?" or say something like "The first time I met him, he chatted like we were old friends. It was bold and annoying."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many colloquial expressions for a *seemingly* friendly, "pushy", person, such as the following:

- presumptuous
- overly familiar
- ingratiating
- oleaginous, oily (q.v., [Hop Frog by E. A. Poe](https://poestories.com/read/hop-frog))
- buddy-buddy
- [hail-fellow-well-met](http://hail-fellow-well-met) (now used often pejoratively, originally not)

See [synonyms for these](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/overfriendly.html), too.

Comment: Of these, _overly familiar_ is by far the most specific to the kind of implication of relationship that OP asked about.